# Did the Sea-Monster serve king Atlan?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, aquaman

In the movie *Aquaman*, Aquaman is attacked by a sea monster who says something like: "no one has conversed with me since king Atlan" and the monster calms down, later the monster fights with Aquaman (after he claimed the trident) in the big battle.

Throughout the rest of the movie I didn't see any confirmation that the monster actually served king Atlan. Maybe I missed something, or it was meant to be left ambiguous. Any clarifying information is appreciated.

Comment: What is getting disappeared O.o

Answer (score 1):

> Did the Sea-Monster serve king Atlan?

What suggests it doesn't?

Karathen was protecting the trident for Atlan and even Atlan was the last one who she can talk to, so of course she was doing Atlan's bidding by protecting the Trident's misuse. But as padfoot mentioned it looks more like allies rather then servitude

Comment: i got the impression that the creature was quite proud, and also when did it say that she was protecting the trident ***for atlan***? I assumed that she was just protecting it against misusers... and Atlan was the last true king so that's why she didn't kill him

Comment: i would assume more of a alliance not servitude, she more ***allies*** herself with Aquaman then serving him from what i could see

Comment: @padfoot edited

Comment: Yeah, I also understood it as the sea monster being an ally or even a friend of Atlan, and since Aquaman reminded him of Atlan, he also chose to help him.

Answer (score 0):

I got the impression that the "sea monster" served the "Ocean Master" and once Aquaman aquired King Atlan's Trident, he became the "Ocean Master" and thus ruled the sea monster and all other sea/ocean creatures.

Comment: Orm was Ocean Master and we never see him controlling sea monster and why would he not get his hand on Trident if he can control sea monster.

Comment: No, Orm wanted to be Ocean Master and was conspiring to gain the title. The "true King/Ocean Master"  would wield Atlan's Trident.

Comment: when it's said only true ocean master will wield the trident ?

Comment: Wasn't that the reason they did the whole journey to the center of the ocean, fight the sea monster, get the Trident... so. like half the movie... all so that Aquaman would be accepted as the "True King" and "Ocean Master"?

Comment: oh, @AnkitSharma, I believe it was in part of Nicole Kidman's dialog...

Comment: In some exposition dialogue Nereus says that according to their laws Orm can only attack the surface world when he has the backing of 4 of the 7 Kingdoms, and at that point he would be ordained "Ocean Master", the commander of their united military force.